# How to make a Pardot autoresponder email send after each download, not just the first

Tags: email-template, form, pardot

I'm fairly new to Pardot, and I'm trying to make an autoresponder email send after every time someone tries to download an image on my site. This is the basic flow:

1. User fills out a quick form (name, company, email, etc)
2. Website sends the form info, including a hidden field with the download link for the resource, to Pardot
3. Pardot adds the user to a list/campaign, and then sends an email to the user with the download link (the hidden field)
4. Pardot reroutes website to a success page

Step 1 is working. Step 2 is working (all correct data is being sent). Step 3 is partially working. The user is added to the campaign. The **first time** someone requests a download, the resource is successful sent using my email template. Step 4 also works.

My issue is that after the first resource download, the autoresponder email is no longer sent, but the user is added to the list and the success reroute work fine.

Is there some setting that prevents emails from being sent for the same prospects?

I don't know a lot about Pardot to know if there is some additional info I need to provide to make this make sense, so please feel free to ask for more.

Answer (score 1):

For step 3 when sending out the email I'd have this as a completion action on the form. So it sends every time.
However, so that the links and content are dynamic. I'd use advanced dynamic content to populate the emails content depending on the hidden field value.

If you dont have advanced dynamic content in your account. You could use repeat automation rules instead.